# Image loader in pagination

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, pagination

[This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0fdH.gif) I have created a page which get the variable and process on it and get the data from the database. 
The data fetched is paginated by pagination function file. 
I want to use a image loader when i click on page 2 the loading image should appear till the data is displayed and once the data is displayed the loading image should disappear.

Here are my files...

```
   <?php
session_start();
if (isset($_GET["topic_name"]))
{   
    $_SESSION['topic_name']=$_GET["topic_name"];
    $topicget = $_SESSION['topic_name'];

}
else
{
$topicget = 'Age';
}
//get the function
include_once('dbconnect.php');
include_once ('function.php');

   $page = (int) (!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
    $limit = 15;
    $startpoint = ($page * $limit) - $limit;


    //to make pagination
    $statement = "`topic`,`author`,`quote` WHERE  ( quote.topics REGEXP '[[:<:]]{$topicget}[[:>:]]' and topic.topic_en= '{$topicget}')and quote.author_id=author.id";
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM {$statement} LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}");

     if($query === FALSE) { 
     die(mysqli_error($con)); // TODO: better error handling
                         }


    ?>

   <html>
   <head>
  <title>Pixster Quotes</title>
  <link href="files/core_msnry.css" media="screen, print" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link href="files/pagination.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="files/grey.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="files/footer-distributed-with-address-and-phones.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

 <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function (){
  $("#imgloader").hide(); //will hide the gif

    $("#masonry").ajaxStart(function(){
            $("#imgloader").show(); //when pagination is clicked, loader will show
              })
            $("#masonry").ajaxStop(function () {
     $('#imgloader').hide();
  });
  });
  </script>


  <style>
  * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
   }

  .item {
    position: absolute;
    margin:10px;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:10px!important;
    width:  300px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    background: #ffff;
    font-size:20px !important;
    text-align:center;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px -9px rgba(28,27,28,1);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px -9px rgba(28,27,28,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px -9px rgba(28,27,28,1);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(00%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(00%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(00%);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease;
     transition: all 0.1s ease;
     }

      .item:hover {
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 29px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 29px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
       box-shadow: 0px 0px 29px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
       -webkit-transform: scale(1.005);
       -moz-transform: scale(1.005);
       -ms-transform: scale(1.005);
       -o-transform: scale(1.005);
        transform: scale(1.005);

      }
     .char a{
     color:white;
     }
    #masonry{
   height:auto; !important;
            }
    #imgloader{
    margin:100px;
              }



   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
   <!--header-->
   <div style="height: 40px;" class="sticky-wrapper" id="bq-tn-id-sticky-wrapper">
   <nav style="" id="bq-tn-id" class="bq-tnav navbar navbar-default bq-cookie-notice ng-scope" data-ng-controller="NavBarCtrl">
   <div class="cl">
   <div class="navbar-header">


   <a class="brand" style="padding:0px 5px 0px 5px; color:white" href="#/"><span class="bqDesktopLogo"></span></a>
   </div>

  <div class="collapse data-ng-cloak navbar-collapse" data-ng-class="navBarClass()" data-ng-click="navCollapsed=true">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="bq-ni hidden-xs bq-nav-large" id="sl-bq-nav-home-t"><a href="http://localhost/quotes/" class="txnav">Home</a></li>
  <li class="bq-ni"><a href="char.php" class="txnav">Authors</a></li>
  <li class="bq-ni"><a href="topic.php" class="txnav">Topics</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav data-ng-cloak navbar-nav navbar-right">

  <li>
  <form action="search.php" method="GET" class="navbar-form navbar-left bq-nav-large no-border bq-no-print navbar-left form-search ng-pristine ng-valid" style="padding-left:8px;margin-top:5px">
  <div class="form-group bq-search">
  <input class="s-btn fa-input fa fa-search" value=" " type="submit">
  <input id="bq-search-input" placeholder="search" maxlength="80" name="q" class="s-fld-t input-medium search-query s-small" type="text">
  </div>
  </form>
  </li>


  </ul>
  </div> 
  </div> 
  </nav></div>

  <!--header ends-->




 <div class="letter-navbar qs-blk" style="text-align: center; letter-spacing: 2px">
 <span class="body bq-tn-letters"> <span id="bq-auth-lbl" class="bq-tn-wrap">Authors:</span>
 <span class="char">
 <?php

 $chars = range('a', 'z');
 foreach($chars as $eachChar){

    echo '<a href="char.php?authchar='.$eachChar.'">'.strtoupper($eachChar).'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                              }
 ?>
 </span>
 </span>
 </div>
  <center><img id="imgloader" src='../quotes/img/loading.gif'/></center>

 <div id='masonry'>



    <center> <h1><strong><?php echo $topicget; echo "  related Quotes";?></strong></h1></center>


   <?php

  $Authorname='';
  $quote='';
  $tag='';
  $NothingFound=true;
  $count=1;
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

        $NothingFound=false;
        $quote =$row['quote'];
        $Authorname =$row['name'];
        $tag =$row['topic_en'];

         ?>
         <div class="item">

     <?php echo $quote; ?><br>
     <?php echo "Author:- {$Authorname}";?>
      </div>
     <?php      $count++;
            }?>

   <?php if($NothingFound){?>
   <div class="item">

     <?php echo "NOTHING FOUND";?>



    </div>
    <?php } ?>

        </div>



    <script src='masonry.pkgd.min.js'></script>
    <script>
    var container = document.querySelector('#masonry');
    var masonry = new Masonry(container, {
    columnWidth: 50,
    itemSelector: '.item'
     });
     </script>


  <?php echo pagination($statement,$limit,$page);?> 

 <div style="margin-top:20px>"<?php include('footer.php');?></div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: does the page refresh when you click next?

Comment: yes. the page refresf and goes to pager=2

Comment: what is the id of your pagination or the id of its div?

Answer (score 0):

Add a gif give it an id='imgloader'.

```
<script>
$(document).ready({
      $("#imgloader").hide(); //will hide the gif

        $("#masonry").click(function(){
                $("#imgloader").show(); //when pagination is clicked, loader will show
                $("#masonry").hide();// to hide your mess data
        });
});
</script>
```

**Edit 1**

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function (){
    $("#imgloader").hide(); //will hide the gif

    $("#masonry").ajaxStart(function(){
            $("#imgloader").show(); //loader will show 
            $("#masonry").hide();// to hide your mess data
    });

    $("#masonry").ajaxStop(function () {
            $('#imgloader').hide();// loader will hide
            $("#masonry").show();// to show your mess data
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: doesn't work. the gif image appear and does not disappear

Comment: you included id='imgloader' in your image?

Comment: yes should I paste here??<img id="imgloader" src='../quotes/img/loading.gif'/>

Comment: image is being diplayed but doesn't work as per we need

Comment: You have to include a jQuery cdn or file.

Comment: loading image is has started working but the mess data still appear with image. I need only image and after that all data should display..

Comment: If the page refreshes, the image should hide again. Use firefox firebug to see if there are errors.

Comment: image hide itself after data loads but while loading data the mess data and image both appear together. I want only loading image to appear and after that data should appear in required format

Comment: This is what should happen according to my answer. When you click next. The loader would show and when the page reloads, it will be hidden again and your new data would show. Question: When you click next, it is still in the same page or not?

Comment: no page changes to loacalhost/quotes/topic.php?page=2

Comment: no error in fact working great but the only problem is data is appear along with loading image.

Comment: I have attached the image have a look.

Comment: The loader is hidden on first visit of the website but the loader won't hide after the page refreshes?

Comment: no...it does hide after refresh but the mess up data as shown in image appears along with the loading image. image is attached in the question at the top.

Comment: What is the div ID of your mess data?

Comment: masonry is the id of div

Comment: your code didnt work so I have used some other jq should i paste it here

Comment: dude still it doesnt work same problem mess up data stilll appear with loading image

Comment: Your mess data is the table with the "Author:" right? And the table and pagination are on the same div?

Comment: no.my mess data is the div with id masonry. the data are the quotes from database and there are no tables in my code all are repeated div inside masonry. pagination is the function called at last.

Comment: Still the same problem?